# Batch-File: Find string in a file and add text after

Tags: batch-file

I generally use the `echo` method for writing "text" to an `HTML`-file by using:

```
  echo. >> "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test.html"
  echo  ^<div^>TestDIV^</div^> >> "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test.html"
```

I've experienced, that `echo` always writes the additional lines to the end of the target file.

But what if my target file (**test.html**) already has a structure like:

```
<div id="wrapperDIV">
    <div id="DIVcontent1">DIV 1</div>
    <div id="DIVcontent2">DIV 2</div>
</div>
```

and I want to write the additional lines within this existing structure, for example right after:

```
<div id="DIVcontent1">DIV 1</div>
```

I have tried to set up a script for this, but so far I couldn't make it running. (It seems to fail in the `for`-loop)

```
set DIVInput=^<div^>TestDIV^</div^>

set inputfile=C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test.html

(for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^=  %%a in ("%inputfile%") do (

   if "%%~a"=="DIV 1^</div^>" call echo %DIVInput%
   echo %%a 
))>>"%inputfile%"

pause
```

Comment: You wouldn't be appending then, would you? I would suggest therefore that you change your title and body text to clarify that you only know how to append, and that's not what you're requiring. Then of course your question would be off-topic, because it would be requesting code, reference links to it, or a methodolody. Please research and write some code.

Comment: @Compo: Thanks for your comment Compo. I have investigated a bit and set up a script.

Comment: `%%a` is the complete line. `if "%%~a"=="DIV 1^</div^>"` will never be true, because there isn't a line `DIV 1</div>` in `test.html`. Also redirecting is done at the very beginning, causing `test.html` to be overwritten before `for` had a chance to parse it. Write to a new file instead and then `move /y test.new test.html`

Comment: Ahhh, thank you very much. I didn't know that it applies on the complete line. Will try it then with a temporary file as transfer-shuttle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `set DIVInput=...` consumes the escaping carets, which is bad in this case, because you need it later to `echo` the variable correctly. The preferred syntax `set "var=value"` preserves them (they are safe inside the quoting).

With your `if` line, you want to check for a substring only, not the whole line (`if` always compares complete strings and doesn't support wildcards). I used `echo fullstring|find "string"` to check that. Note that I use quotes (`echo "%%~a"') for the same reason as above: proper handling of poison chars like`>`and`<`Same reason for not escaping with the`find` command ("save inside quotes")

You redirect to your input file. Redirecting is the first thing for the parser, so the file gets overwritten even before `for` has a chance to read the file. Use a different file and overwrite your original file when done.

You want to insert a string *after* a certain trigger line, but your code inserts *before* that line (well, that's easy to fix).

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set "DIVInput=^<div^>TestDIV^</div^>"
set inputfile=test.html
(for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^=  %%a in ("%inputfile%") do (
   echo %%a 
   echo "%%~a" |find "DIV 1</div>" >nul && echo     %DIVInput%
))>"%inputfile%.new"
REM move /y "%inputfile%.new" "%inputfile%
```

Note: I disabled the `move` command for security reasons. Remove the `REM` after checking `test.html.new` looks ok.

Comment: Hello Stephan. Thank you very much for the detailed answer and for sharing your expert knowledge. You helped me a lot to understand the script better and of course to fix my issue. Hats off!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it works, but blank lines are removed.

```
`enter code here`@echo off
`enter code here`setlocal 
`enter code here`set "DIVInput=^<div^>TestDIV^</div^>"
`enter code here`set inputfile=test.html
`enter code here`(for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^=  %%a in ("%inputfile%") do (
   `enter code here`echo %%a 
   `enter code here`echo "%%~a" |find "DIV 1</div>" >nul && echo     %DIVInput%
`enter code here`))>"%inputfile%.new"
`enter code here`REM move /y "%inputfile%.new" "%inputfile%
```